# React Native Element Type is Invalid

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to render some footer tabs in a React Native app but I'm not sure what in the following code is coming back as undefined.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { Text, TabBarIOS } from 'react-native'

FooterTabs.propTypes = {
    activeFooterTab: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onTabSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    navigator: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default function FooterTabs (props) {
    return (
        <TabBarIOS>
            <TabBarIOS.item
                title='home'
                icon={{}}
                selected={props.activeFooterTab === 'home'}
                onPress={() => {props.onTabSelect('home')}} >
                <Text>Home</Text>
            </TabBarIOS.item>
            <TabBarIOS.item
                title='camera'
                icon={{}}
                selected={props.activeFooterTab === 'camera'}
                onPress={() => {props.onTabSelect('camera')}} >
                <Text>Camera</Text>
            </TabBarIOS.item>
        </TabBarIOS>
    )
}
```

activeFooterTab function

```
export default function activeFooterTab (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_FOOTER_TAB : 
            // Returns the tab we pass in to the action creator. 
            return action.tab
        default : 
            return state
    }
}
```

onTabSelect function

```
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
    return {
        onTabSelect: (tab) => dispatch(setFooterTab(tab))
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: the 'item' in 'TabBarIOS.item' may need to be capitalized as shown in their example here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.31/docs/tabbarios.html

Comment: Whoops. That was it. Thanks!